# Resorting kendo UI grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

this should be a simple one, but i cannot find anything which is getting annoying, has anyone else had luck with this one...

i am adding item to kendo datasource that is bound to a grid. is there a way i can resort the grid??

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.add(data);
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.sort();
```

or when i cann the 
    `$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();` this should sort it

really can't get anything to work, i'd like to be able to dynamically add records to grid, and have the grid resort.

this is how i am defining my grid in my cshtml page

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.List)
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Width(100);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Age).Width(100);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(100);
})
.Events(events => events.Change("onChange").DataBound("onDataBound"))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(m => m.Id(g => g.Gid))
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetName", "NamesController", new { Id = Model.Id }).Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
    .Sort(sort => {
        sort.Add(p => p.Id);
        sort.Add(p => p.Age);
        sort.Add(p => p.Name);
    })

    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Datasource has a `sort` method (documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#methods-sort)). Basically you need to fix the sort criteria and then invoke this method.

Example:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
    { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ]
});
dataSource.sort({ field: "age", dir: "desc" });
```

Comment: so every-time i add data to datasource object i need to redefine the sort criteria? that doesn't seem right..

Comment: No, you might define the sort criteria in the datasource as well so it should be sorted.

Comment: Check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/LT9p7/ You will see that the added element is automatically inserted in the _right_ place.

Comment: i don;t what the difference is, i added how i am defining my grid in cshtml page, i don't know why it is not working..

Comment: Is it initially sorted (before adding the new element)? Did you try defining the sorting direction (Ascending / Descending)? At least in JavaScript you have to define the sorting direction (no default direction).

Comment: it will sort everytime i render the page, so i am guessing i need to define my grid and data source in JS instead of cshtml...which is CRAP!!!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47983/discussion-between-onabai-and-wingman20-10)

Answer (score 0):

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource        
 .Ajax()
 .ServerOperation(false)        
)
```

basically setting  .ServerOperation(false) fix this. this will enable client side sorting